# I want to associate File With Custom Object but getting Error

Tags: lightning, files, contentversion

I am trying to create new File through ContentVersion and Associating it with Custom Object ParentId is ID of Custom Object .

Error given is 
Document: You cannot create a link for a document in a private library.

EXCEPTION_THROWN [356]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You cannot create a link for a document in a private library: [ContentDocumentId]

Following is my Code ,

```
        public ID createFileFromUploadedFile(Id parentId) {
        ID docID = null;
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.versionData =  file.Body;
        cv.title = file.FileName;
        cv.pathOnClient = file.FileName;
    insert cv;

    docID = cv.id;
        ContentVersion currentDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId from 
                                     ContentVersion  where id =:docID];
        docID = currentDoc.ContentDocumentId;
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = currentDoc.ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
        cdl.ShareType = 'S';
        insert cdl;

    return docID;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add location for the file (the library), I use `ContentLocation` for creating my `ContentVersion`:

```
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S = within Salesforce, E = External
    cv.VersionData = body;
    cv.Title = fileName;
    cv.PathOnClient = filename;

    insert cv;
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this the other day while converting a process that was using attachments to use the new Files feature.  What fixed it for me was setting the `FirstPublishedLocationId` to the record.

So in your example

```
public ID createFileFromUploadedFile(Id parentId) {
        ID docID = null;
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.versionData =  file.Body;
        cv.title = file.FileName;
        cv.pathOnClient = file.FileName;
     ** cv.FirstPublishLocationId = parentId **
    insert cv;
```